# Python request yields status code 500 even though the website is available

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python to check whether or not a list of websites is online. However, on several sites, requests yields the wrong status code. For example, the status code I get for https://signaturehound.com/ is 500 even though the website is online and in the Chrome developer tools the response code 200 is shown.

My code looks as follows:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def url_ok(url):

   r = requests.head(url,timeout=5,allow_redirects=True,headers=headers)
   status_code = r.status_code

   return status_code

print(url_ok("https://signaturehound.com/"))
```

Comment: Maybe the `head` request is not supported on that website, using `get` works fine.

Comment: I get error code 500

Comment: @WasifHasan me too, when I tried `.get` I got `200` status code

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci Sometimes solutions can be beautifully simple. Thanks a lot! Changing head to get is working for me.

Comment: @JakobGreenfeld If you found your solution I would suggest you post your solution as an answer to this question so that people who view this post later can quickly find the answer.

Comment: Is it 404 or 500? Please edit the question to make it accurate.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @CaptainDaVinci in the comments, the solution is to replace `head` by `get` in the code:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def url_ok(url):

   r = requests.get(url,timeout=5,allow_redirects=True,headers=headers)
   status_code = r.status_code

   return status_code

print(url_ok("https://signaturehound.com/"))
```